# What is the difference between subgame perfect Nash-equilibrium and backwards induction?

Tags: real-analysis, game-theory

I cannot find any difference, except for that the subgame perfect Nash-equilibrium yields a strategy rather than an action, between those two solution concepts. To me, it seems like you always just use backwards induction when finding the subgame perfect Nash-equilibrium. If that is the case, why would you spend time defining two things that really are the same (if I am not being wrong, which I guess I am)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not really the same thing. Sub-game perfectness of a solution like the Nash equilibrium is a desirable **consistency property** of a solution concept, i.e., no sub-group of players should have an incentive to deviate from a Nash-equilibrium to play from a particular node onward their own sub-game to improve their payoffs.

However, backwards induction is a **solution procedure** to compute Nash-equilibria of a game while making use of the desirable feature of sub-game perfectness of that solution concept.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Ahh so backwards induction is a procedure and the subgame perfect Nash-equilibrium is a property of the game? That would make more sense to me, however, why does some book like "A Primer in Game Theory" by Gibbons then explain about those two things as two separate procedures? For instance, for dynamic games with perfect information, (a_1^*,R_j (a_1^*)) is the solution for player j with backwards induction, where (a_1^*,R_j (a_1)), is the solution for the subgame perfect Nash-equilibrium? Please help, it is for a very important assignment, thank you so very much!

Comment: Can you provide more information about the reference. Page, Section, for instance.

Comment: Of course I can! Link: https://is.muni.cz/el/1431/jaro2013/M9302/um/39389090/Gibbons.pdf Pages: 57-60(backwards induction) Pages 122-127(subgame perfect Nash-equilirbium). You can for example take a look at the formula for backwards induction at page 58  and for subgame perfect Nash at page 122 - like there are two different ways to solve then, which is just one of the things that confuses me since I cannot find the actual difference and they both seem to be a solution procedure..

Comment: As far I see, Gibbons makes the difference that an equilibrium is based on a complete plan of action, which is a strategy, whereas an outcome happens only in the contingencies that are expected to arise (p.125). Thus, he considers $R_{2}(a_{1}^{*})$ as an action, and $R_2(a_{1})$ as a strategy. That is based on his assumption that sub-games are single-person decision problems. But this is incorrect. In my opinion the presented arguments are not compatible with the definition of a Nash-equilibrium. In addition, his definition on page $125$ is not clear at all.

Comment: (cont.) Finally, it is not clear why is $a_{1}^{*}$ is a best response to $R_2(a_{1})$ (p.125). He gives no resilient argument. His argumentation is not a proof. I think this book is not a good source to learn game theory. You should take a look in the van Damme book "Stability and Perfection of Nash equilibria".

Comment: Wow okay, thanks! But so the actual and main difference between those two things is that backwards induction is a procedure and the subgame perfect nash is a property?

Comment: Yes, that it is.

Comment: Great, thanks! One more thing though: I know that it is quite random, but can you mention any situation between two firms where game theory would predict another result than what would be the actual result in reality?

Comment: There is a vast literature in Experimental Economics analyzing exactly this issue. These studies found evidence that people do not behave as selfish as the theory would predict. Years ago I did in this respect some research before my attention changed to some other topics. Nevertheless, I think that the following source could serve as an entrance in this topic: https://doi.org/10.1007/s10100-006-0019-2

Comment: Damn, you have saved my life. Thank you!!! It means so much to me!!